# Why do I get API: Wearable.API is not available on this device when I try to connect my handheld device app to wearable using android?

Tags: java, android, wearables

I am trying to build an android app that can connect to a smartwatch, I've followed the official docs on [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/events) to use the DataLayer to connect both devices, right now I am struggling with finding the connected nodes so I can get the nodeId of the wearable and use it to connect to the watch.

This is what I did so far:

```
private Collection<String> getNodes() {
    HashSet<String> results = new HashSet<>();

    Task<List<Node>> nodeListTask =
            Wearable.getNodeClient(this).getConnectedNodes();

    try {
        List<Node> nodes = Tasks.await(nodeListTask);

        for (Node node : nodes) {
            results.add(node.getId());
        }

    } catch (ExecutionException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Task failed: " + exception);

    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interrupt occurred: " + exception);
    }

    return results;
}
```

but I get this error when I launch the app:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Wearable.API is not available on this device.
```

I also followed [the sample](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/DataLayer) provided by google and I still couldn't fix this issue, I searched here on StackOverflow and on the official docs and I would appreciate it if someone can guide me on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a faced similar issue ! try installing the [wearOS app](https://cliq.zoho.com/company/64396901/chats/2243193296531663099/messages/1672338896130_20179352974594) and try again.

Comment: did this help you fix the error ?

Comment: Sorry @Divesh I haven't gotten to it yet, I've been trying to use [gadgetbridge](https://github.com/ydon1111/Gadgetbridge) to connect to my smart watch.

Comment: Is this [the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app) you mentioned?

Comment: YES ! Install it and now you won't get the "API not available" error

Comment: thanks for confirming, I am working on another project currently, I'll try that when I have time and let you know!